# Curl like use in Erlang

Tags: curl, erlang

I'm trying to move some code from shell scripts to erlang for a new internal tool.

The current shell script calls curl like this:

```
curl \
  --header "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
  --data @$OTAR_SOAP_FILE \
  --output $OTAR_OUT_FILE \
  --stderr $OTAR_ERR_FILE \
  --insecure \
  $OTAR_URL
```

I want to be able to do the same from erlang using the inets' library.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work:

```
stress(Url, Message, ConcurrentAttempts, Attempts) ->
    setup_connection(),
    {ok, {{Version, ResponseCode, ReasonPhrase}, Headers, Body}} = 
        httpc:request(get, {Url, [], "text/xml", Message}).
```

In this case, URL is the same as $OTAR_URL and Message is the contents of $OTAR_SOAP_FILE.

How can I pass the OTAR_URL the data from the soap file in erlang the same as I do it via curl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using [httpc:request/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-2), which expects two parameters: a Url and a Profile. You're passing 'get' as the URL and a tuple as a Profile, which is obviously wrong:

```
httpc:request(get, {Url, [], "text/xml", Message}).
```

You probably want to have look at the other variants of the httpc:request function, such as [httpc:request/4](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-4).

As a note, always add the specific error you get. It *usually* contains the reason of the error and makes easier for other users to spot what the actual problem is.

Comment: Can you give an example of using httpc:request/4? I'm new to erlang and it's documentation is a bit opaque.

Comment: I understand that, but how would I pass it string with a bunch of data on the GET?

Comment: Either you pass the data as part of the query string (i.e. http://www.google.com/search?q=http%20protocol) or you perform a 'post' request and you append a body (httpc:request(post, {Url, [], ContentType, Body}, [], [])).

Comment: Using POST is what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

why bother ? You can use your script from Erlang. I have used this technique for years now. There is a function called: [**os:cmd/1**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1). It is used to execute a command, or a script using the underlying operating system.

```
Remember that curl is an advanced HTTP Client. Most of the Erlang HTTP Clients
 lack most features that curl has e.g. NTLM Authentication, seemless Proxy
 authentication,seemeless Cookie support, e.t.c.
```

Some time this year, i was working on a script behind an NTLM authenticated proxy and all Erlang HTTP Clients came to a stand still at this. Hence this is what was required

```
curl \ 
     --proxy {PROXY}:{PORT} --proxy-ntlm --proxy-user \ 
     '{Domain}\{Username}:{Password}'  {Link}
```

To use curl in erlang to make such a simple GET request, this is what i did:

```
curl(Link)->
    Cmd = "curl -X GET \"" ++ Link ++ "\"",
    Output = os:cmd(Cmd),
    Output.
```

All you need to do is to escape all string variables to curl, especially the {Link}

 All requests you make with curl can still be made with curl from Erlang. An example which writes the output to a file works like this:

```
curl(Link,OutputFile)->
    Cmd = "curl -X GET -o \"" ++ OutputFile ++ "\" \"" ++ Link ++ "\"",
    os:cmd(Cmd).
```

In such a case, we will not get any output in erlang because we have told curl to throw all output into a file.
 Hence its possible to execute any script, any termninal program, any command with Erlang

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>erl
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> os:cmd("echo \"Erlang is great!!!!\" ").
"\"Erlang is great!!!!\" \r\n"
2> [io:format("~s~n",[X]) || X <- string:tokens(os:cmd("ping google.com"),"\r\n")],ok.
Pinging google.com [173.194.78.113] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.78.113: bytes=32 time=273ms TTL=45
Reply from 173.194.78.113: bytes=32 time=272ms TTL=45
Reply from 173.194.78.113: bytes=32 time=274ms TTL=45
Reply from 173.194.78.113: bytes=32 time=275ms TTL=45
Ping statistics for 173.194.78.113:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 272ms, Maximum = 275ms, Average = 273ms
ok
3>
```

Comment: From the doc: "The functions in the OS module are operating system specific. Careless use of these functions will result in programs that will only run on a specific platform.". Also, os:cmd/1 is a "synchronous" operation. Something to always bear in mind.

Comment: true. But then, i thought that would be obvious. One needs to ensure that `curl` is in `$PATH` wether the system will run on windows or linux. `cygwin` on windows comes with curl, an environment in which an erlang application can run. But i am sure that if one knows that their application depends on curl, why not make sure its installed ?

Comment: Erlang in most cases doesnot build client-Desktop applications. we use it more on the backend servers. If your application depends more on Lunix/Unix scripts, why deploy it on a windows server ?

Comment: `curl` is asynchronous yes. But even with `inets`, or `ibrowse`, you will still need to wait for connections to return results. I do not see any difference. `curl` has been used in conjuction with `php`, `perl`,`python`,`c++` for many years now. Spawn an process and let it send a message when curl has returned result, or synchronously wait for the returned results: depends on the application

Comment: Using curl from the command line isn't an option in this case. Not all places where the application will be deployed will have curl. Specifically: windows.

Comment: Agreed; However, its very possible to have curl on windows. Haven't you heard of curl.exe ?

Comment: I'm not happy with the value that os:cmd returns. When I run a curl command from shell I get a json response, but with os:cmd I get it back with a bunch of extra data pre-pended - "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r100   116  100   116    0     0  55715      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  113k\n